# Grouping EntityType in CollectionType by overlying Entity

Tags: php, forms, symfony, collections, doctrine

I want to create a many to many relation between to tables throug my form. I'm working on a game with several questions for an customer. He can register and give answers to given questions. the relation I want to set is between Customer and Answer Table.

So i render the fields which are needed for the customer. Now I want to render some questions with their possibly answers.

In given Code you can see that I add in my EventListener the form field "answers" as CollectionType of EntityType of "Answer::class", but the array I set at "data" is of type "Question::class".

Now he is rendering my three questions, but with every posibile answer - not in relation to actual rendered question.

I tried working with "query_builder" option, but didn't found a solution.

ERM: https://i.ibb.co/bgjmPsF/adventskalender.png

**Customer.php**

```php
<?php

namespace App\Entity;

use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\CustomerRepository")
 */
class Customer
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id()
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue()
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $name;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255, unique=true, nullable=false)
     */
    private $email;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="boolean", nullable=true)
     */
    private $dse_checked;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="boolean", nullable=true)
     */
    private $reminder_checked;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="datetime", options={"default"="CURRENT_TIMESTAMP"})
     */
    private $registration;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="boolean", nullable=true)
     */
    private $newsletter;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="App\Entity\Answer", inversedBy="customers")
     * @ORM\JoinTable(name="customer_answer")
     */
    private $answers;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->registration = new \DateTime("now");
        $this->answers = new ArrayCollection();
    }

    public function getId(): ?int
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function getName(): ?string
    {
        return $this->name;
    }

    public function setName(string $name): self
    {
        $this->name = $name;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getEmail(): ?string
    {
        return $this->email;
    }

    public function setEmail(string $email): self
    {
        $this->email = $email;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getDseChecked(): ?bool
    {
        return $this->dse_checked;
    }

    public function setDseChecked(?bool $dse_checked): self
    {
        $this->dse_checked = $dse_checked;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getReminderChecked(): ?bool
    {
        return $this->reminder_checked;
    }

    public function setReminderChecked(?bool $reminder_checked): self
    {
        $this->reminder_checked = $reminder_checked;

        return $this;
    }


    public function getRegistration(): ?\DateTimeInterface
    {
        return $this->registration;
    }

    public function setRegistration(\DateTimeInterface $registration): self
    {
        $this->registration = $registration;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getNewsletter(): ?bool
    {
        return $this->newsletter;
    }

    public function setNewsletter(?bool $newsletter): self
    {
        $this->newsletter = $newsletter;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @return Collection|Answer[]
     */
    public function getAnswers(): Collection
    {
        return $this->answers;
    }

    public function addAnswer(Answer $answer): self
    {
        if (!$this->answers->contains($answer)) {
            $this->answers[] = $answer;
        }

        return $this;
    }

    public function removeAnswer(Answer $answer): self
    {
        if ($this->answers->contains($answer)) {
            $this->answers->removeElement($answer);
        }

        return $this;
    }

    function __toString(): string
    {
        return $this->getName();
    }
}
```

**Question.php**

```php
<?php

namespace App\Entity;

use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\QuestionRepository")
 */
class Question
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id()
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue()
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="text")
     */
    private $value;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="App\Entity\Winning", inversedBy="questions")
     */
    private $winning;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="App\Entity\Answer", mappedBy="question", cascade={"persist"})
     */
    private $answers;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->answers = new ArrayCollection();
    }

    public function getId(): ?int
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function getValue(): ?string
    {
        return $this->value;
    }

    public function setValue(string $value): self
    {
        $this->value = $value;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getWinning(): ?Winning
    {
        return $this->winning;
    }

    public function setWinning(?Winning $winning): self
    {
        $this->winning = $winning;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @return Collection|Answer[]
     */
    public function getAnswers(): Collection
    {
        return $this->answers;
    }

    public function addAnswer(Answer $answer): self
    {
        if (!$this->answers->contains($answer)) {
            $this->answers[] = $answer;
            $answer->setQuestion($this);
        }

        return $this;
    }

    public function removeAnswer(Answer $answer): self
    {
        if ($this->answers->contains($answer)) {
            $this->answers->removeElement($answer);
            // set the owning side to null (unless already changed)
            if ($answer->getQuestion() === $this) {
                $answer->setQuestion(null);
            }
        }

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function __toString(): string
    {
        return $this->getValue();
    }
}
```

**Answer.php**

```php
<?php

namespace App\Entity;

use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\AnswerRepository")
 */
class Answer
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id()
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue()
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $value;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="App\Entity\Question", inversedBy="answers")
     */
    private $question;


    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="boolean", nullable=true)
     */
    private $isRight;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="App\Entity\Customer", mappedBy="answers")
     * @ORM\JoinTable(name="customer_answer")
     */
    private $customers;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->customers = new ArrayCollection();
    }


    public function getId(): ?int
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function getValue(): ?string
    {
        return $this->value;
    }

    public function setValue(string $value): self
    {
        $this->value = $value;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getQuestion(): ?Question
    {
        return $this->question;
    }

    public function setQuestion(?Question $question): self
    {
        $this->question = $question;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getIsRight(): ?bool
    {
        return $this->isRight;
    }

    public function setIsRight(?bool $isRight): self
    {
        $this->isRight = $isRight;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @return Collection|Customer[]
     */
    public function getCustomers(): Collection
    {
        return $this->customers;
    }

    public function addCustomer(Customer $customer): self
    {
        if (!$this->customers->contains($customer)) {
            $this->customers[] = $customer;
            $customer->addAnswer($this);
        }

        return $this;
    }

    public function removeCustomer(Customer $customer): self
    {
        if ($this->customers->contains($customer)) {
            $this->customers->removeElement($customer);
            $customer->removeAnswer($this);
        }

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @return string|null
     */
    public function __toString()
    {
        return $this->getValue();
    }
}
```

**CustomerType.php**

```php
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $this->questions= $options['questions'];
        $builder
            ->add('name', TextType::class, ['label' => 'Name', 'mapped' => true,])
            ->add('email', TextType::class, ['label' => 'E-Mail'])
            ->add('dse_checked', CheckboxType::class, ['label' => 'Datenschutzbestimmungen akzeptiert'])
            ->add('reminder_checked', CheckboxType::class, ['label' => 'Tägliche Erinnerungen'])
            ->add('newsletter', CheckboxType::class, ['label' => 'Newsletter abonieren'])
            ->addEventListener(FormEvents::PRE_SET_DATA, [
                $this,
                'onPreSetData'
            ])
            ->add('submit', SubmitType::class, ['label' => 'Speichern']);
    }


    /**
     * @param FormEvent $event
     */
    public function onPreSetData(FormEvent $event)
    {
        $form = $event->getForm();
        $questions  = $this->questions;

        foreach ($questions as $wKey => $question) {
            $answers = array_merge($answers, $question->getAnswers()->getValues());
        }

        $form->add('answers', CollectionType::class, [
            'entry_type' => EntityType::class,
            'data' => $questions,
            'by_reference' => false,
            'mapped' => true,
            'entry_options' => [
                'label' => 'Label',
                'class' => Answer::class,

            ]
        ]);
    }
```

In the end I want a list of question with their relationl answer options in my customer formular so that i can save the given answers to my customer entity.

Comment: So, not clear, it gives you some error, or you do not yet know what/how to write? Also, can you add your entities' code, as seeing actual relations and their annotations is important here? Finally, are you sure your `customer_answer` does not need a reference to 3rd table like session? Currently it looks like every customer have exactly one chance to answer every question, and cannot pass same quiz again (that's unrelated to your question, just curious re your business model/logic).

Comment: why would you use one `answer` form field for multiple values? I would put the form->add into the foreach loop and set the choices property there as well and use property_path to handle the mapping

Comment: @alx I've added my relatet entities to my question. Problem is that I don't know how i have to write it. Logic should be correct, every customer ca only answer a question once. Every answer is related to extactly one question. If i want to change my given answers, old given answer will be removed.

Comment: @Jakumi "answers" is the field name of entity "customer" and should be a collection of given answers. So it should be the right way to add answers to a customer, shouldn't it?

Comment: Thanks, that helps. I'm not sure why you add a relation between customer and answer without `customer_answers` in the middle.

Comment: @alx 'cause the customer_answer table just saves the relation between customer and answer, i'dont need any special fields in that join table. so in the form i'll show a collection of possible answers to save. or how should i do it the right way?

Comment: I know it *technically* is the collection of answers. but semantically there isn't just *one* question but many. so all answers are not equal, some may appear at the same time, but some cannot. hence: for each question add a form field "answersID" (ID == id of question) and set `property_path` to something like `answers[ID]`, which you can easily do in the loop, and then you limit the answers to the question for each subfield. the property path should put all the answers into one array(collection). I'm not sure if it works or needs some tweaks...

Comment: @Jakumi I've tried and it works, thanks mate. But how can i render them dynamicly in my form template? For example I can render question/answer 1 with "{{ form_row(customerForm.answers1) }}" , but i don't know how many questions i've to render.

Comment: you can loop over all form fields via `{% for childname, child in customerForm %}` and maybe insert a guard: `{% for childname, child in customerForm if childname starts with 'answers' %}`

Comment: @Jakumi Thanks alot. I've worked so much at it, now I've everything I wanted to have. So my first feeling to use CollectionType in form was sadly wrong.. think i've to learn more about symfony forms.